# image not showing it's correct path when rendering in image Component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am working on a messaging system where user can post message along with image using **react.js** and **node.js**. In node part, i used **multer** library for storing my file and that is working without causing any problem. Here is My code in **node end**:

> app.js:

```
const postRoutes = require('./routes/post');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

app.use('/images',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'images')));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) =>{
        //ensure that this folder already exists in your project directory
        cb(null, "images");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb)=>{
        let extension = file.originalname.split('.')[1];
        cb(null, "image-"+Date.now().toString() + '.' +extension)
    }
});

const imageFileFilter = (req, file, cb) =>{
    if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) { 

        req.fileValidationError = "You can upload only image files";
        return cb(null,false, req.fileValidationError);
    }
    cb(null, true)
};

app.use(multer({storage: storage, fileFilter: imageFileFilter}).single('image'));

app.use('/post', postRoutes);
app.use((error,req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(error);
    const statusCode = error.statusCode;
    const message = error.message;
    res.status(statusCode).json({message:message});
});

mongoose.connect(dbUrl)
    .then(()=>{
        app.listen(8080);
        console.log('DB is Connected . Application Start in 8080')
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

> routes/post.js :

```
const express = require('express');

const postController = require('../controllers/post');

const Post = require('../model/post.model');
const router = express.Router();

// GET /post/messages
router.get('/messages', postController.getPosts);

// GET /post/message/:id
router.get('/message/:id', postController.getPostById);

// POST /post/message
router.post('/message',
    Post.validation,
    postController.createPost);

// Put /post/message/:id
router.put('/message/:id',
    Post.validation,
    postController.updatePost);

module.exports = router;
```

> postController.js :

```
exports.createPost = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
    console.log(req.file)
  if(!errors.isEmpty()){
    const error = new Error('Validation Failed, entered data is not valid');
    error.statusCode = 422;
    throw error;
  }
  if(!req.file){
      const error = new Error('Invalid Image File');
      error.statusCode = 422;
      throw error;
  }
  const imageUrl = req.file.path;
  const title = req.body.title;
  const content = req.body.content;
  const post = new Post({
    title: title,
    content: content,
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    createdBy: {
      name: 'lorem_ipsum'
    }
  });
```

After creating a post output results saved in db:

```
{
  title: 'Texts',
  imageUrl: 'images\\image-1653121355433.jpg',  
  content: 'Text content',
  creator: { name: 'lorem ipsum' },
  _id: new ObjectId("6288a14b5b9b0ae87b069a08"),
  createdAt: 2022-05-21T08:22:35.438Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-05-21T08:22:35.438Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

But when i am trying to fetch the data and showing in react application the url is breaking.
in my **view page** image div showing blank and the response I get from **api** :
[image: my image]

As you can see my imagePath is : **http://localhost:8080/images\image-1653121355433.jpg** but react application removing the middle slash and filepath become **http://localhost:8080/imagesimage-1653121355433.jpg**

here is my view page and image component :

> **SinglePost.js** :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Image from '../../../components/Image/Image';
import './SinglePost.css';

class SinglePost extends Component {
  state = {
    title: '',
    author: '',
    date: '',
    image: '',
    content: ''
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const postId = this.props.match.params.postId;
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/feed/post/' + postId)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status !== 200) {
          throw new Error('Failed to fetch status');
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(resData => {
        console.log(resData.post)
        this.setState({
          title: resData.post.title,
          author: resData.post.creator.name,
          image: 'http://localhost:8080/' + resData.post.imageUrl,
          date: new Date(resData.post.createdAt).toLocaleDateString('en-US'),
          content: resData.post.content
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="single-post">
        <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
        <h2>
          Created by {this.state.author} on {this.state.date}
        </h2>
        <div className="single-post__image">
          <Image contain imageUrl={this.state.image} />
        </div>
        <h1>{this.state.image}</h1>
        <p>{this.state.content}</p>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default SinglePost;
```

> and **Image.js** :

```
import React from 'react';

import './Image.css';

const image = props => (
  <div
    className="image"
    style={{
      backgroundImage: `url('${props.imageUrl}')`,
      backgroundSize: props.contain ? 'contain' : 'cover',
      backgroundPosition: props.left ? 'left' : 'center'
    }}
  />
);

export default image;
```

**Can anyone help me to sort this problem out ?
What am i missing in my code ?**

Comment: Backslashes work on your file system, but not in a URL. Convert it to a forward slash: `http://localhost:8080/images\image-1653121355433.jpg` -> `http://localhost:8080/images/image-1653121355433.jpg`. (Also, in Javascript `"\i" === "i"`, because backslashes must be escaped by another backslash.)

Comment: @HeikoTheißen thank you for your help. converting backslash into forwardslash help me to sort out rather than Escaping Backslash .